# Unable to install any printer

Tags: installation, printing

I am unable to install any printer, local or network.

I just did a clean install 11.10, the CUPS driver is loaded. I even un-installed it and reinstalled it. Same problem. The add printer button is grayed out. Unable to access any part of the add printer page, top line menu or button.

Comment: Please tell us, if you use ubuntu or kubuntu and what name the printer has.

Comment: When you run system-config-printer, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

answer, you need to use that horrible Unity interface in order to install printers and perform other tasks.  If you've installed the Gnome Classic interface, you can see printers, but it will not allow you to install/modify any.

Log out, log back in using the Unity "Ubuntu" desktop and you can manage your printers, once that's done, escape to sanity back to the Classic Gnome.